# How to connect Kafka to legacy Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, legacy

I am working on PoC of connecting legacy Spring application to Kafka. It is `war` application to be deployed in Tomcat, Spring version 4.3.12. Is there some library to make communication with Kafka almost as easy as with Spring Boot? I need just fundamental operations: sending message, listening for confirmation, receiving.

I have some experience with Spring Boot support as is provided in `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka` library. I am not sure how to efficiently adopt Kafka for legacy Spring - I'm thinking of using [Kafka Java client](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/java/current/overview.html#ak-java) which looks promising but as I am used to working at Spring Boot abstraction level I don't have clue how much code should I supply myself.

Web search is not much helpful in this case since it tends to show Spring Boot-related solutions. Migration of legacy application is considered too, I just need to have some idea how difficult each way is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kafka-clients` is all you need (from Maven Central, not Confluent). You could go a step further and look into Log4j2 Kafka bridge, then property files for that.

If you want to externalize config into regular Java `.properties` file, you can, or you can pull values from environment variables, if you follow 12-factor principles.

But if you don't already have Spring Boot dependencies, then I do not think adding them is worth it for only Kafka.

Also, the Spring-Kafka documentation covers how to configure your app **without** Boot.

Comment: Yes, with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/1.3.11.RELEASE (which has kafka-clients 0.11.0.3) I managed to connect do Kafka 2.7 and send some messages. Thanks for advice.

Comment: You should use a later version which has at least kafka-clients 2.7 dependency